# Invalid form control (type=url) is not focusable when hidden in Chrome

Tags: html, asp.net, validation, google-chrome

I'm encountering a problem in Chrome where form submission results in the following error:

```
An invalid form control with name='ctl00$cphMain$ctl01$groupControl$website' is not focusable.
```

This is an `<input type="url" ...>` rendered in Chrome inside a `<div>` that has `display:none` set (until the neighbouring checkbox is checked). There is no `required` attribute, nor is there a `maxlength` attribute set, so I'm unsure as to why the submission fails. Here is the relevant section of markup (the control in question is inside the 2nd `<fieldset>`):

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl01_groupControl_ctl13" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphMain$ctl01$groupControl$ctl13" onclick="$(this).parent().siblings('div.expandableContainer').slideToggle();"/>
    Include contact...
</label>
<div class="expandableContainer form-expanded js-initial-hide " style="display: none;">
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            Name:
            <span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input name="ctl00$cphMain$ctl01$groupControl$name" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl01_groupControl_name"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            Website:
            <span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input name="ctl00$cphMain$ctl01$groupControl$website" type="url" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl01_groupControl_website" value="http://" onblur="if (this.value == 'http://') this.style.color = '#666';" onfocus="this.style.color = '#000';" style="color:#666;"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            Email:
            <span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input name="ctl00$cphMain$ctl01$groupControl$email" type="email" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl01_groupControl_email"/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

According to W3.org (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls), this is supposedly a 'successful' control. Even adding a MaxLength of 2000 (the DB field width) doesn't work. No errors are received for the surrounding controls.

Is there any idea why this form submission is failing? Checking the box (to cause the surrounding `<div>` to be displayed (with `display:block`) allows the form to be submitted without any problems.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I discovered the problem: The invisible URL fields (`<input type="url" ... />`) had a non-empty value set (basically part of a legacy JavaScript solution to implement placeholder text). For some reason, this value in an invisible field trips up Chrome (possibly from their built-in validation, that other people discussing similar issues have alluded to). Perhaps Chrome misses the lack of visibility specified in the ancestor `<div>`.

How I fixed this:

- Removed the `onblur`, `onfocus` and `style` attributes as they are redundant;
- Changed the `value` attribute to the new HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, keeping the same attribute value.

The only drawback is that site visitors must manually enter the "`http://`" in the field rather than append to it; our project team will discuss strategies to improve the UX of this.